# How to set destination path in pdf2image using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6. I have to convert a PDF to an image and for that, I am using the pdf2image npm package. My PDF gets converted into an image but I am not able to set a destination path for it. Below is my code snippet.

```
pdf2image.convertPDF('/NodeWorkspace/uploads/photo-1533016241503.pdf',{
    density : 200,
    quality : 100,
    outputFormat : '%s_page_%d',
    outputType : 'png',
    path: '/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/'
})
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: any error for the path?

Comment: @kaushik Andani no, it doesn't give any error but the converted image placed on default project path

Comment: try with
path: '/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/'

Comment: @KaushikAndani tried already not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to set destination path in pdf2image using Angular.

```
var dirPath=path.join(__dirname,'../../uploads/output/'+req.body.appNo)+'/%s_page_%d';

pdf2image.convertPDF(pt,{
        density : 200,
        quality : 100,
        outputFormat : dirPath,
        outputType : 'png'

    })
```